# (function(){ })(); Разобраться со всем

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
var test = (function(){
 this.test2 = function(){};

 return function(){};
})();
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, толково, какую роль играют последние скобки ();. Зачем нужны, как использовать?

И почему я не могу использовать функцию `Test2` вот так `test.test2`?

```
var test = function(){
     this.test2 = function(){};

     return function(){};
    };
```

Даже при такой записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Объясните, пожалуйста, толково, какую роль играют последние скобки ();. Зачем нужны, как использовать?

Выполняют заключенную в предыдущие скобки функцию, передавая дальше переданные аргументы.

```
(function (i) { console.log(i); })(12); // в консоли появится 12
```

> И почему я немогу использовать функцию Test2 вот так test.test2?

1. Не с глаголами пишется раздельно
2. Потому что код внутри function еще не выполнился, а при попытке выполнения new test он вернет функцию, к которой никоим образом не обращались (this.test2 в этом случае относится к другому объекту).

Классический пример использования замыкания - фиксация переменной на определенном значении путем размещения ее в области видимости замыкания, недоступной извне.

```
var printers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    printers.push(
        (function (i) {
            return function () {
                console.log(i); // i в этом случае будет найдено в родительской функции, в противном случае эта i была бы одинакова для всех 15 функций.
            }
        })(i);
    );
}
```